# use variables inside if and for loop

Tags: windows, batch

I have the following code:

```
echo off
set n=11
set m=12
set /a nme=3
set /a mdiff=nme-1
pause
if %n% NEQ %m% (
    if %mdiff% LEQ 3 (
        for /l %%C in (1,1,3) do (
            if %%C EQU 1 (
                set mon=Apr
            )
set num=1%mon%
        )
    )
)
echo %num%
pause
```

which gives me output `1` instead of `1Apr`. However when I place `set num=1%mon%` outside all if and for loops it gives correct result.

Please explain me what happened here and how to obtain the correct result inside the loops.

Also, what is the maximum depth of `if` and `for` levels?

Comment: You have declare the variable `mon=Apr` and not concatenate with 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need to do is put a [`SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) at the top of your script and use `!`s around your variables.

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the `SETLOCAL` command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables may be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal `%variable_name%` )
>
> Delayed variable expansion is often useful when working with `FOR` Loops, normally an entire `FOR` loop is evaluated as a single command even if it spans multiple lines of a batch script.

Basically, the `for` loop gets parsed once. Each iteration of the loop, the statements get executes. By enabling this option, the variables can change on execution, without reparsing, i.e. within the loop.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set n=11
set m=12
set /a nme=3
set /a mdiff=nme-1
pause
if %n% NEQ %m% (
    if %mdiff% LEQ 3 (
        for /l %%C in (1,1,3) do (
            if %%C EQU 1 (
                set mon=Apr
                set num=1!mon!
            )
        )
    )
)
echo %num%
pause
```

Comment: Thank you Bob! it works well, however in a similar code below it does not help. Please help to found out what happened.@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set ys=11
set ye=12
set /a nme=9
set jan=Jan

if %ys% NEQ %ye% (
echo in if
pause
set /a mdiff=nme-1
  if %mdiff% LEQ 9 ( 
 for /l %%B in (1,1,%mdiff%) do (
   for /1 %%C in (1,1,31) do (
     if %%B EQU 1 (
  set monthe=Jan
  echo !monthe!
  )
     if %%B EQU 2 (
  set monthe=Feb
  echo !monthe!
  )
     REM xcopy "C:\Tests\conversion\Data.%ye%\Month.%monthe%\Day.0%%C" 
   )
 )
   )
)
echo %monthe%
pause

Comment: @Anna I can't read that. Please put it on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) (and give me the link in a comment) or add it to your question. It would help if you explained what you want it to do.

Comment: Bob, the code is here http://pastebin.com/5xisFyGV. It is just a fregment of a big script which convert files from one format into another. The main difficulty is that files should be taked from particular folders by date range (e.g. 01/02/2011 - 02/04/2012). Moreover output files should be placed in a separate directory but coping the original hierarchy. I'm not a programmer so my code is quite long. This bit of code is a core which would search a data by year-month-date. And it doesn't work starting after the first "pause" line I don't know why. Please help

Comment: @Anna This kind of help is better done through [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) (you'll need to register a SuperUser account, then we can create a chat room) or through a new question, not comments. I will say you probably should be using `!nme!` in line 13, but there may be other errors. Also, if this answer helped you with this particular question (variable in loop), please [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) by clicking the tick to the left.

Comment: I have written this code differently http://pastebin.com/WzJffFKh. It is executable but it looks like variable 'mark' does not change its value even if the condition is true. What the reason can be?

Comment: @Anna Keep in mind that there's no Boolean in Windows batch files. `true` is the literal string "true". Use `1` and `0`. Once again, if this answer helped, please [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask) by clicking the tick to the left. It prevents the question from coming up as unanswered and being automatically bumped every now and then.

Comment: It works now!!!! For those seeking a script to do something in a range of dates this can be helpful http://pastebin.com/amtrzvNq