# Batch File: Loop Not Outputting Inputted Variable Value to External File

Tags: command-line, script, batch-file, cmd.exe, input

The problem lies in this part of the code:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %num%) do (
   set /p "inp=Enter Ext of PC: "
   echo pc-%inp%x>>"Myfile.log"
)
```

Here is the full code:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: +++++++++++++++++++ MENU +++++++++++++++++++++
:menu
cls
echo.
echo 1) Add PCs to Log File
echo 2) View Log File
echo 3) Exit
echo.
goto option

:option
set /p op=Type option #:
if "%op%"=="1" goto addext
if "%op%"=="2" goto viewcnt
if "%op%"=="3" goto exit


:: ++++++++++++++++++++ OPTIONS ++++++++++++++++++++++

:addext
:: Enter Number of PCs to Add to Log File
echo.
set /p "num=Enter Num of PCs to Add: "
echo.
goto addlog

:addlog
:: Create/Clear Log File/Enter Computer Extensions/Write to Log File
cls
echo.
echo.>"Myfile.log"
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %num%) do (
   set /p "inp=Enter Ext of PC: "
   echo pc-%inp%x>>"Myfile.log"
)
echo.
pause
goto menu

:viewcnt
:: View Log File
type Myfile.log
echo.
pause
goto menu

:exit
@exit
```

---

### Objectives

Enter Number of PCs to Add to Log File - *Works*

```
set /p "num=Enter Num of PCs to Add To: "
```

Output:

```
Enter Num of PCs to Add To:
```

---

Create / Erase Log File (each time option 1 of menu is choosen) - *Works*

```
echo.>"Myfile.log"
```

---

Set variable `%inp%` for each of the Number of Computers from `%num%` variable - **Need Help**

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %num%) do (
   set /p "inp=Enter Ext of PC: "
   echo pc-%inp%x>>"Myfile.log"
)
```

Output:

```
Enter Ext of PC:
```

(Iterates the number of times `%num%` is equal to)

- Prompts for input of extension variable for the number of times prescribed by previous input - *Works*
- Able to type in each extension - *Works*
- Not sure what happens to the variable entered - **Need Help**

---

Write the Variables to the Log File - **Need Help**

```
echo pc-%inp%x>>"Myfile.log"
```

- The prefix preceding the variable shows the number of times entered - *Works*
- Not including the inputted variables - **Need Help**

---

View Log File - *Works*

```
type Myfile.log
```

**Further Considerations:**

- `pc-%inp%` is the computer name ( prefix: pc- ) followed by
  (variable: `%inp%` / example: **pc-a001** )
- `%inp%` needs to be    Alphanumberic ( one letter followed by 3
  numbers: **a001** )

Comment: [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Thank you for your input, but I am still getting the same results. I inserted the EnableDelayedExpansion:
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo.>"Myfile.log"
    for /l %%x in (1, 1, %num%) do (
       set /p "inp=Enter Ext of PC: "
       echo pc-%inp%x>>"Myfile.log"
    )

Comment: You missed the point. Your need to replace `-%inp%x` with `-!inp!x` as well.

Comment: Wow!!! I did miss that totally!!! Thanks. Also the x in _!inp!x_ is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that works:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
echo.>"Myfile.log"
for /l %%x in (1, 1, %num%) do (
   set /p "inp=Enter Ext of PC: "
   echo pc-!inp!>>"Myfile.log"
)
```

Changes needed were:

- adding the SETLOCAL `EnableDelayedExpansion`
- changing `%inp%x` to `!inp!`

Thanks to [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) for your help